# Visual Studio 2012 Test Controller Connection Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, load-testing

We have a Visual Studio 2012 test controller. When attempting to connect from a machine with Visual Studio 2012 installed, I can connect to the test controller and queue a test with no issues.  When I attempt to connect to it and run a test from my development machine running Visual Studio 2013 however, I get the following error:

Cannot connect with controller ''. If the controller service is not started you may be able to start it by clicking the restart rig button.

The following error was received:
Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerObject'.

Can VS 2013 not connect to a VS2012 test controller? We are running TFS 2012 which VS 2013 has no issues with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client is newer than the test controller which is not supported scenario. There is no cross-compatibility between VS2013 client and VS2012 controller.